# Flutter Build Apk: Build Failed to notify build completion listener

Tags: build, flutter, release

I have flutter installed and working with no issues, I can code and build debug apk's and hot reload but I can't build a release version of my application.

Here is "flutter doctor -v" and "flutter build apk" information from CommandPrompt.

**C:\eew>flutter doctor -v**

```
**[√]** Flutter (Channel dev, v0.10.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.10.1 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 6a3ff018b1 (11 days ago), 2018-10-18 18:38:26 -0400
    • Engine revision 3860a43379
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.7.1.flutter-b99bcfd309

**[√]** Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Scott Robertson\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

**[√]** Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

**[√]** VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.28.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

**[√]** Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G610F • 5203698b48575407 • android-arm • Android 7.0 (API 24)

• No issues found!
```

**C:\eew>flutter build apk**

```
Initializing gradle...                                       1.9s
Resolving dependencies...                                    4.5s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify build completion listener.
> com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       37.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

**Here is "flutter build -v apk" information**

```
[        ] Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
[   +3 ms] executing: [C:\eew\android\] C:\eew\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget=lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=false -Ptarget-platform=android-arm assembleRelease
[+29288 ms] [  +10 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +119 ms] [ +148 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] [   +1 ms] origin/dev
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[ +122 ms] [ +129 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] [        ] dev
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[ +126 ms] [ +119 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +101 ms] [ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] [        ] 6a3ff018b199a7febbe2b5adbb564081d8f49e2f
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[ +112 ms] [ +110 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] [        ] 12 days ago
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long
--tags
[ +103 ms] [ +110 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] [        ] v0.10.1-0-g6a3ff018b
[+1452 ms] [+1451 ms] Building bundle
[   +2 ms] [        ] Writing asset files to
C:\eew\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release/flutter_assets
[ +173 ms] [ +179 ms] Wrote C:\eew\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release/flutter_assets
[  +10 ms] [  +10 ms] "flutter bundle" took 1,433ms.
[+1063 ms] 22 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 17 up-to-date
[ +201 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Failed to notify build completion listener.
[        ] > com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more
           log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 32s
[ +554 ms] Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed)
[  +31 ms] "flutter apk" took 44,753ms.
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:399:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:300:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:41:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:44:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:383:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#12     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#13     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure>
(dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: What an active community :|

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after I upgraded my flutter beta channel from v0.10.2 to v0.11.3. I spent hours to figure out this issue.
Hope this will work for you as well:

**Method 1:**

- Rename the folder `android` to `android.save`
- Create another flutter project named dummy
- Copy the `android` folder from the dummy project
- Replace the `android\app` folder by previous saved folder (`android.save\app`)
- Run a clean build:

  `flutter clean;flutter build apk --release --verbose`

**Method 2:**

Switch to a different flutter channel, then switch back may also fix this issue. It worked for me on another machine.